# Expo location not working, App.json is properlly set

Tags: ios, react-native, expo

I've been following a guide to build a location tracker, but I constantly get the error

"Error: One of the `NSLocation*UsageDescription` keys must be present in Info.plist to be able to use geolocation."

And

"Error: Background Location has not been configured. To enable it, add `location` to `UIBackgroundModes` in Info.plist file."

Which doesn't make much sense since I already put both of the required stuff in the app.json

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native";
import MapView from "react-native-maps";
import * as Location from "expo-location";
import * as TaskManager from "expo-task-manager";

const LOCATION_TASK_NAME = "background-location-task";
export default function Screen() {
  const [region, setRegion] = useState<{
    latitude: number;
    longitude: number;
    latitudeDelta: number;
    longitudeDelta: number;
    heading: number | null;
  }>({
    latitude: 0,
    longitude: 0,
    latitudeDelta: 0.045,
    longitudeDelta: 0.045,
    heading: null,
  });
  const getLocationAsync = async () => {
    Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, {
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
      distanceInterval: 1,
      timeInterval: 500,
    });
    const newLocation = await Location.watchPositionAsync(
      {
        accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
        distanceInterval: 1,
        timeInterval: 10000,
      },
      ({ coords }) => {
        setRegion((prev) => ({
          ...prev,
          latitude: coords.latitude,
          longitude: coords.longitude,
          heading: coords.heading,
        }));
      }
    );
    return newLocation;
  };

  const permissionHandler = async () => {
    const { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
    if (status === "granted") {
    //   const { status: backgroundStatus } =
        // await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
    //   if (backgroundStatus === "granted") {
        getLocationAsync();
    //   }
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    permissionHandler();
  }, []);
  return <Text>Test</Text>;
}

TaskManager.defineTask(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, async ({ data, error }: any) => {
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    return;
  }
  if (data) {
    const { locations } = data;
    let lat = locations[0].coords.latitude;
    let long = locations[0].coords.longitude;
    console.log(lat, long);
  }
});
```

App.json

```json
{expo:{
...
"permissions": [
      "location",
      "fetch"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true,
      "infoPlist": {
        "UIBackgroundModes": [
          "location",
          "fetch",
          "remote-notification"
        ],
        "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription": "Your app needs access to location when in use for...",
        "NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription": "Your app needs access to location even when the app is in the background for...",
        "NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription": "Your app needs access to location even when the app is in the background for..."
      }
    },
"plugins": [
    [
      "expo-location",
      {
        "locationAlwaysAndWhenInUsePermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to use your location.",
        "locationAlwaysPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to use your location."
      }
    ]
  ]
}}

I tried clearing the cache, didn't work, resetting the app, also didn't work....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"Error: One of the NSLocation*UsageDescription keys must be present in Info.plist to be able to use geolocation."
solution 1 : https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/12662

"Error: Background Location has not been configured. To enable it, add location to UIBackgroundModes in Info.plist file."
solution 2 : https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/8349

solution 3 : https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/location/

solution 4 : Remove the comments from the lines that ask for background permissions, and see if that fixes the problem : // const { status: backgroundStatus } = await Location.requestBackgroundPermissionsAsync();
// if (backgroundStatus === "granted") {

solution 5 : Verify that after the permissions are granted, startLocationUpdatesAsync is being called. It could be a good idea to move the startLocationUpdatesAsync call inside the permission status check block.
const permissionHandler = async () => {
  const { status } = await Location.requestForegroundPermissionsAsync();
  if (status === "granted") {
    await Location.startLocationUpdatesAsync(LOCATION_TASK_NAME, {
      accuracy: Location.Accuracy.BestForNavigation,
      distanceInterval: 1,
      timeInterval: 500,
    });
    getLocationAsync();
  }
};
```